# Solve in Z. $y^2+y=x^4+x^3+x^2+x$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Solve in Z. $$y^2+y=x^4+x^3+x^2+x$$

In my attempt to solve this, I used the fact that the left side is even.I write the eqyation in the following form: $$(x+1)(x^2+1)=0 \pmod 2$$. This clearly means x must be an odd number, as a result $$4|y(y+1)$$. This is as far as I could go.

> Question from Jalil Hajimir

Comment: The right side factors as $x(x+1)(x^2+1)$, not $(x+1)(x^2+1)$, so $x$ need not be odd, as the solution $(x,y)=(0,0)$ confirms.

Comment: THanks,You are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Bound between 2 squares

For all but finitely many values of $x$, we can bound $(2y+1)^2$ between 2 consecutive perfect squares, hence it is never a perfect square.

> $(2x^2 + x)^ 2 < (2y+1) ^2 = 4y^2 + 4y + 1 = 4x^4 + 4x^3 + 4x^2 + 4x + 1  < 4x^4 + 4x^3 + 5x^2 + 2x + 1 = (2x^2 + x + 1)^2 $

Hence, we only need to check those values when the inequalities fail:

RHS inequality is false when: $x \in [0, 2 ] $.
$x = 0$ yield $ y = -1, 0$.
$x = 1$ yields no integer solution for $y$.
$x = 2$ yield $ y = -6, 5$.

LHS inequality is false when $x \in [-1, -\frac{1}{3} ]$.
$x = -1$ yields $y = -1, 0$.

Comment: This means $2x^2+x<2y+1<2x^2+x+1$

Comment: Yes, and $2y+1$ is an integer. What integers are there between those 2 consecutive intgers?

Comment: $2x^2+x $ is an odd number

Comment: Not necessary. It has the same parity as $x$. Note that you are missing the point: Are there any integers that lie strictly between $2x^2+x$ and $2x^2+x+1$?

Comment: thanks, of corse not.

Comment: Can you please introduce a refrence to get more familiar with this method or another example

Comment: The idea of bounding between two squares (or cubes, or triangle numbers, etc) is pretty common for similar setups, though I don't know of a reference off-hand that focuses just on that. Consider cases where you can get it to look like a square (leading coefficient is even). E.g. When is $n^6 + 24n^3 +192$ a perfect square, or a perfect cube?

Comment: Thank you ver much. My mentor also told me he is not aware of any reference for this method. I was wondering where I can find more information

Comment: Do we consider (n^3+12)^2 and (n^3+13)^2 to find perfect sure?

Comment: Just be careful with positive/negative values. And take a larger range which might simplify some calculations.

Comment: n is integer, not positive integers

Comment: If n is an integer we solve we consider two cases  n>0 and n<0. Am I right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101668/discussion-between-keon-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: I need help on this